# [Hardware]How to Fix pulseaudio Failed to set switch of Headphone: Input/Output error?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I'm a students from China.I have a problem.Please help me.Thanks

I tried use

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

Now I can find my device,but it still heve no sound.

There are some logs https://paste.debian.net/1265027
[ksystemlog](https://forums.debiancn.org/uploads/default/original/2X/f/f523e0aae2375d31aa21e0debb4eef8f86a44344.png).

[my computer's information](https://forums.debiancn.org/uploads/default/original/2X/f/f5b4c6bc0d9b7ed1e62dfec31a12ec2e0cfc75d9.png)

You can find more informations on https://forums.debiancn.org/t/topic/3518/7

I tried a lots of ways to fix it.But nothing work.